# How to redirect output from start-ed console?

Tags: batch-file, redirect

I have the following command: **C:\start MyApp.exe Parameter > C:\Temp\result.log**.  I have this in batch file. The output is not redirected to result.log. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your command is

```
start MyApp.exe Parameter > result.log
```

This logs the output of the `start` command only, and that output is always empty.

If you want to redirect the output of the *called* program you need to escape the redirection.
But the redirection only works, when parsed by cmd.exe, else it's only a parameter to the application.

```
start cmd /c MyApp.exe Parameter ^> result.log
```

Comment: I actually tried ^>, but yet, the output is logged to the new console and is not redirected.

Comment: I now tried this and it worked. c:\start cmd /C MyApp.exe ^> result.log