# How to both redirect output and have a console window for a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to use
`subprocess.Popen(["start", "/wait", "program"], shell=True)` to have my program open in a new window. At the same time, I want to be able to capture output (stdout), for example by using `subprocess.PIPE`. However, if I simply add the pipe directive (stdout=.. in popen) , the pipe is of the `start` program which prints nothing.

I tried to follow [How to redirect output from start-ed console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275345/how-to-redirect-output-from-start-ed-console) and use :

```
            v = ["start" ,"/wait", "program", "^>1"]
```

but it didn't work (hangs on readline).

I know I can use log file, but kind of inclined against (because of buffering mainly).

Comment: I've written what gets as close to an answer I can get with the information you provided below. However, can you explain what you might want to do with the captured output, to give a sense of whether the solution I suggested might work?

Comment: Is the requirement to run the process in a new window really necessary? This would not be hard to do if that can be relaxed.

Comment: I just want to capture the line "Ready" in time. That appears quite near the start of run. File thing would probably be ok. Hoped for something better.

Comment: The two requirements are the essence of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start` command will try to start whatever `program` is as a new process and if `program` is console-based, a new console window will open for it to write output (and errors) to and possibly receive input from.

Assuming your application `program` is console-based, it only has a single `stdout` stream, which the console window will receive and echo on the window.

As you found, redirecting the `stdout` of the start command itself doesn't help, since it doesn't actually write anything to standard out (when all is well) - it only serves to launch the other program.

For example, if you tried something like this:

```
start /wait C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE 8.8.8.8 -t
```

... you would see the output in a new console, and nothing in in the calling window / process.

If you tried to redirect the output like this:

```
start /wait C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE 8.8.8.8 -t > test.txt
```

... that wouldn't work either, since it would just be redirecting the output from `start`, which is nothing.

But this also doesn't work:

```
start /wait C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE 8.8.8.8 -t ^> test.txt
```

... since there isn't anything to apply the escaped redirect to. That's why the question you linked suggests this:

```
start /wait cmd /c C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE 8.8.8.8 -t ^> test.txt
```

This almost works, in that it starts the process, opens the window and runs the program, and captures the output in a file. But it does all of this from the new process, not in the calling process.

However, you want the text from the `program` to still show up on the new console window, as well as have live access to the same output in your script (in your case not to redirect it to a file, but presumably use it in some other way).

You can get close by starting the command in the new console with PowerShell, using `Start-Process` instead of `cmd /c` and using `Tee-Object` which is similar to the Linux `tee` command.

However, this only succeeds in writing the output to a file as well as to the console, all from the new console. You could of course monitor the file for changes from your Python script, but this would still only get you new data whenever `Tee-Object` flushes the file buffer to disk. I don't think there's a way for you to get this to work using normal console windows in Windows, simply due to the way those work, and the fact that you can't just redirect a stream from one process to another using console windows.

The solution here might be to write a Python script that runs in the new console window, both echoing the data to the console as well as processing it. You just launch this helper script from your original script and the effect is exactly what you need. You'd have to provide more details to explain why that wouldn't be a suitable solution in your case.

Comment: I agree and was aware of the solution of teeing in one way or another. I think winapi might be able to. But complicated.

Comment: I think a helper script to run your program in the console is the way to go. From the script you have control over the title, the text output, just like any console program, and so you can run the program and have the console window behave the same as it would otherwise. From that helper script, you can then do some basic processing and send whatever you need to extract from the output to your main application by some suitable means. To say what the best way to do that would be, I'd need to know more about what exactly you need to do to the output (filter, search, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`start` is a shell command, not a separate program. The `Popen` function redirects the output of the program it runs, not the output of shell commands.

We could try to create a batch file that starts your program and redirects its output to a file, and then run this batch file with `Popen`.

Lets do a `start.bat` batch file which contain:

```
start /wait program > output.txt
```

Then we can run it with `Popen` like that

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["start.bat"], shell=True)
```

Comment: This redirects the output, but OP wants the output to show up in the console window as usual, while being able to redirect a copy of the output to their originating process. Also, this answer redirects to file - something OP indicated they are aware of, but isn't sufficiently direct for their purposes.